# If respond_to? not returning anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have a bit of code that is supposed to be checking whether or not a method call exists for an attribute, it seems neither the if or else are returning anything...

```
%h2= @post.title
    .row                    
        .col-sm-12
            = render "blog_meta", :post => @post
            #text_body
                = @post.content
            %hr
            - if @post.comments.count > 0
                %h2 Comments
                #comments
                    - @post.comments.where(:original_id => nil).each do |comment| 
                        .comment
                            .profile
                                %img{:src => "/assets/profile_image_sample.jpg"}
                            .message
                                .username
                                    - if comment.user.respond_to?('username')
                                        .username= comment.user.username
                                    - else
                                        .username= comment.user.first_name
                                = comment.content
                                - logger.info "LOGGER--->>" + comment.user.first_name
                                .reply-link
                                    %a{:href => "#"} Reply to Comment
                        - if comment.replies.count > 0
                            - nesting = 0
                            - comment.replies.each do |comment|
                                = render "comment", :comment => comment, :nesting => nesting
                %hr
            = render "submit_comment"
```

However if I simply `= comment.user.first_name` with no conditionals then it works fine..

Comment: alternatively you could add this sort of method to your `User` model `def name; username || first_name; end` then you can just call `user.name` on your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most likely the `user` responds to `username` but it is `blank` or `nil`. You might want to do this instead

```
    - if comment.user.username.blank?
        .username= comment.user.first_name
    - else
        .username= comment.user.username
```

`respond_to` is used to check if a method is defined for the object. It will return `true` if the method is defined for the object. It does not concern what the output of that method is.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you, what is respond to typically used for?

Comment: One brief comment on the code style. It's generally better to use the condition withought the `!` sign. So in a situation like this you just switch the `if` and `else` blocks and remove that `!`. If you don't have an `else` block, just use `unless`.